# wpf how to bind usercontrol property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi I am trying to bind user control property but so far not successful. Below is my code.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
       mc:Ignorable="d" 
       d:DesignHeight="120" d:DesignWidth="120"
       x:Name="uc"
       Background="Transparent">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox> 
           ......
           <CheckBox Name="Start" Visibility="Hidden" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Animation, ElementName=uc, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
           .......
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User control code behind.

```
  public partial class MyControl: UserControl
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Animation", typeof(bool), typeof(CircularProgressBar));
    public bool Animation
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(AnimationProperty); }
      set 
      {
        SetValue(AnimationProperty, value); 
      }
    }


    public MyControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      //(this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }

  }
```

View code

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="cpb" Animation="{Binding CpbIsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

View Model code

```
private bool cpbEnabled;
public bool CpbIsEnabled
{
  get { return cpbEnabled; }
  set { cpbEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged("CpbIsEnabled");  }
}

public ICommand ShowSelFlagCommand
{
  get
  {
    return showSelFlagCommand ?? (showSelFlagCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
    {
      if (CpbIsEnabled) { CpbIsEnabled = false; }
      else { CpbIsEnabled = true; }
    }
    ));
  }
}
```

I put a break point in Animation property set method in user control code behind. But when ICOmmand in view model executes it never reach the break point. In other words, the Animation property is not set by the binding.

Can someone tell me what I have missed?

Thanks,

Comment: Animation property set method will not get called by a binding. That property is only used when getting or setting in code

Comment: The Animation property is not set by the binding. How can I make it work?

Comment: I believe that you use the standard Property syntax as a wrapper for the DependencyProperty. The getter is fine, but the setter should ONLY call SetValue(AnimationProperty, value);

Comment: Ultimate facepalm.  If it's a DependencyProperty you don't need to implement INPC.

Comment: I changed the setter to call SetValue(AnimationProperty, value) but still not working. Anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) within your control's code-behind.

After you have implemented a dependency property for your control, the property will be exposed in your XAML.

Comment: Hi Scott I did implement the dependency property AnimationProperty. Please see the second code block. And Animation property was exposed. The problem was that the binding did not work. Any idea?

Comment: You don't need SetValueDP. Just use SetValue. Remove your INotifyPropertyChanged dependency in your code-behind as well. Using MVVM will resolve many of your issues.

Comment: I commented out SetValueDP and removed INotifyPropertyChanged dependency in code-behind. but the binding was still not working?

Comment: Property "CpbIsEnabled" does not match "CpbEnabled" that you're notifying a propertychange with

Comment: Thank you for finding that out. Corrected it in the code but the binding still not working.

Comment: Is the property actually receiving different values?

Comment: DP Binding mechanism doesn't use instance getters and setters internally. Breakpoint in the setter will not trigger unless you set it in code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured this out. Much thanks for all who have helped.

User control code

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2visibility" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Viewbox>
      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsLoading, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource bool2visibility}}">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform x:Name="SpinnerScale" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"   
                    Width="120" Height="120" >
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="20.1696" 
                  Canvas.Top="9.76358" 
                  Stretch="Fill" Fill="Orange" 
                  Opacity="1.0"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="2.86816" 
                  Canvas.Top="29.9581" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.9"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="5.03758e-006" 
                  Canvas.Top="57.9341" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.8"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="12.1203" 
                  Canvas.Top="83.3163" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.7"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="36.5459" 
                  Canvas.Top="98.138" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.6"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="64.6723" 
                  Canvas.Top="96.8411" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="87.6176" 
                  Canvas.Top="81.2783" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="98.165" 
                  Canvas.Top="54.414" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="92.9838" 
                  Canvas.Top="26.9938" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.2"/>
          <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                  Canvas.Left="47.2783" 
                  Canvas.Top="0.5" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Fill="Black" Opacity="0.1"/>
          <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name ="SpinnerRotate" Angle = "0" />
          </Canvas.RenderTransform>
          <Canvas.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent ="ContentControl.Loaded" >
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="CirccularProgressBarStoryBoard">
                  <DoubleAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetName ="SpinnerRotate" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty ="(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                    From="0" To="360" 
                    Duration="0:0:01" 
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
          </Canvas.Triggers>
        </Canvas>
      </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
  </Grid>
```

User control code-behind.

```
  public partial class CircularProgressBar : UserControl 
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLoadingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsLoading", typeof(bool), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
    public bool IsLoading
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(IsLoadingProperty); }
      set { SetValue(IsLoadingProperty, value); }
    }

    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }
  }
```

View axml

```
<local:CircularProgressBar  x:Name="cpb" IsLoading="{Binding CPBLoading}" >
```